# How to close program while not focussed with java

Tags: java, javafx

I made an auto clicker program just to speed up something, and I want to be able to close this by pressing Minus while not focussed, now it works, but it has to be focussed.
Does anyone know a way of doing this, not having to focus the GUI?
If it helps, here is my Key event handler class:

```
class handler implements EventHandler<KeyEvent> {



@Override
public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
    if(event.getCharacter().equals("-"));
    System.exit(0);
}

}
```

Comment: You'd have to have software listening for keyboard events and communicating with or directly terminating your java application.

Comment: This sounds like a terrible idea. You're typing along in some arbitrary program while this is running in the background, press the "minus" key, and accidentally kill the program...

Comment: The auto clicker is supposed to be runned when the person is not on the pc, so not really, I'm not working with any APIs, I just use the robot class to simulate my clicks.

Comment: I though screensavers was only sleeping when the computer was used, or have I got this completely wrong? Typically I would not like a program to unexpectedly close when running something else. This is not really what I would expect of it.